# angular 5 - modal directive

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs-directive, angular5

This is my first time on Angular using typescript. I've been really trying hard to create this modal directive, inspired from [ngMorph](http://jimobrien.github.io/ngMorph/).

This are working fine as expected but I've run across a very weird issue. When I click on the button to open the modal box, it works just as fine and I close the modal box, it closes. When I try to open the same modal box again and try to close, it doesn't close. And it doesn't throw any error as well.

After debugging, I found that `modal-active` class in the `modal-button` is not getting removed.

HTML

```
<div class="modal-button edit-sample-modal" [appModal] data-modal="edit-sample-modal">Open Modal</div>

<div class="custom-modal" id="edit-sample-modal">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="text-default">
        <i class="fa fa-close fa-fw close-modal"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

Here's my code for the modal

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, AfterViewChecked, Input, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[appModal]'
})
export class ModalDirective implements AfterViewChecked {

    @Input()
    appModal: string;

    constructor(
        private element: ElementRef
    ) { }

    ngAfterViewChecked() {
        // function to go here
        this.initModalBox(this.element.nativeElement, this.element.nativeElement.getAttribute('data-modal'));
    }

    @HostListener('click') onclick() {
        this.initModalBox(this.element.nativeElement, this.element.nativeElement.getAttribute('data-modal'));

        const modalElement = document.getElementById(this.element.nativeElement.getAttribute('data-modal'));

        this.element.nativeElement.classList.toggle('modal-active');
        modalElement.classList.toggle('modal-open');
    }

    initModalBox(button: HTMLElement, modalDialog: string) {
        const trigger: HTMLElement = button;
        const triggerPos = trigger.getBoundingClientRect();

        const modalElement = document.getElementById(modalDialog);

        modalElement.style.top = `${triggerPos.top}px`;
        modalElement.style.left = `${triggerPos.left}px`;
        modalElement.style.height = `${triggerPos.height}px`;
        modalElement.style.width = `${triggerPos.width}px`;

        modalElement.style.position = 'fixed';

        const closeElement = modalElement.getElementsByClassName('close-modal')[0];

        closeElement.addEventListener('click', function () {
            modalElement.classList.toggle('modal-open');
            // this.element.nativeElement.classList.toggle('modal-active');
            document.getElementsByClassName(modalElement.getAttribute('id'))[0].classList.toggle('modal-active');
        });
    }
}
```

I do know the code is not perfect, I'm just learning things and I've come up with this so far. I was even wondering of using jQuery but I don't want to use it Angular project, I'm trying to make do it the angular way without using jQuery. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `data-modal="edit-sample-modal"` if you see this is not the id you are targeting. The target element's ID is `edit-item-modal`. You can use hostlistener to close the modal dialog too.

Comment: I'm sorry, that was my mistake, when I was changing the actual class name I forgot about that. My modal is all working fine when I open it for the first time, but for the second time when I open the modal, I'm not able to close it.   `modal-active` is not getting removed though I've got a function to toggle the class `closeElement.addEventListener`

Answer (score 7):

For modal in Angular with typescript one can go with bootstrap.
You can find modal example in this link..
Click [here](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals)!

1: Import ModalModule to your module as below:

```
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
@NgModule({
imports: [ModalModule.forRoot(),...]
})
export class AppModule(){}
```

2:Add below line into your .html file

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="staticModal.show()">Static modal</button>

<div class="modal fade" bsModal #staticModal="bs-modal" [config]="{backdrop: 'static'}"
     tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">Static modal</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="staticModal.hide()">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        This is static modal, backdrop click will not close it.
        Click <b>&times;</b> to close modal.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thats it!

Comment: Hey, thanks! I know about the bootstrap modal, the reason why I've created it this way, I'm doing a morphing effect. If I'm going to do it with bootstrap, I'll again have to write those function to set the position of the element.

Comment: @Saurav Hey, did you ever solve this? I would also love to have an Angular 5 version of ngMorph

Comment: @Inigo Hey,sorry i have not  tried.Actually have not used ngMorph

Answer (score 0):

This is for bootstrap 4.1.X and angular 6.0.X

modal.html

```
<!-- MODAL TRIGGER -->
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" appModal>Launch Modal</button>

<!-- MODAL -->

<div class="modal" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal Title</h5>
        <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal" appModal>&times;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus unde veniam harum magnam molestias dignissimos omnis
        architecto, quod, obcaecati dolorum debitis dolore porro qui, iusto quo accusantium voluptates pariatur illo.
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" appModal>Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

appModal.directive.ts

```
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appModal]'
})
export class AppModalDirective {

constructor() { }

  @HostListener('click') modalOpen(){
    document.getElementById('myModal').classList.toggle('d-block');
  }
}
```